# Sql ask about substraction two fields

Tags: php, sql

I want to ask how to make something like this:

Ive got two tables lets call it `A` and `B`. `A` has a `amount_a` and in `B` we have `amount_b`. I want to ask how to make `amount_a` - `amount_b` and then the result asign to `amount_a`. How can I make it ? All simple examples nice to see. Thank you very much

Comment: you'll need to join the tables, is there a link between them? can you show us your schema?

Comment: You have one row in each table?

Comment: @Alexander, no, but I want to make operation on this two rows.

Comment: You'll need to show us your database schema

Comment: @user3310467 which **this**? If you have more than one row in each table, how will rdbms find out which one and when you wanna use?

Comment: Are there any common columns to join? let's say there are 10 rows in each table, how do you want subtract a and b?

Comment: @thelastshadow yes, table B has foreign key of table A row

Comment: do you need it in one query?

Comment: @Alexander On one row in table A and one row in table B

Comment: @Shocked if it is possible, yes. I wish it could be like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple example (`JOIN`ing on `id`):

`CREATE` two tables with five rows of numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
   id int auto_increment primary key
 , amount_a int(2)
);

INSERT INTO table_a (amount_a)
VALUES (6),(72),(58),(39),(0);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
   id int auto_increment primary key
 , amount_b int(2)
);

INSERT INTO table_b (amount_b)
VALUES (1),(23),(31),(14),(51);
```

Query:

```
SELECT
   amount_a - amount_b AS amount
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b9c6/1

Results in:

```
amount
5
49
27
25
-51
```

And running an `UPDATE` to `amount_a`:

```
UPDATE table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
SET amount_a = amount_a - amount_b
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c39e/1

Comment: can you make up vote for my post ? I get banned..

Answer (score 0):

You can create two tables and join them (perhaps on an ID).  And then select amount_a - amount_b from the joined result as shown in this SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5334/4